# How to open large (10gb+) Text files and edit them

Tags: text-editor, large-files

I Have large  .txt file, over 10gb
I should open this file and make simple editions:
- remove duplicate lines
- split this file (like 5x2gb files)

What software I need? Windows pref... But if not possible Linux can be great too.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
    EmEditor
```

On Windows, you can install an application called "EmEditor".

This application can open large files. It is a licensed application however you can use it for a one month trial period. Make the change and uninstall.

I had faced this issue where I couldn't edit a large 4GB .sql file. This tool editor was the only editor which could get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [Vim](https://vim.sourceforge.io/) or [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)

I would recommend using Vim since it's packed with [Git bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/)

You quit Vim with **:q**
and if the buffer changed you can quit without saving with **:q!**

If Vim if not for you, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files) answer and [this](https://www.petri.com/tip-opening-large-files-windows) link, maybe the editors sugested in those links are better suited for you.

[Vim CheatSheet](https://vim.rtorr.com/)

[Removing duplicated lines using Vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Uniq_-_Removing_duplicate_lines)

[Split file using Vim (vi.stackexchange.com)](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/487/how-do-i-break-a-file-into-two)

Comment: I don't think vi is good for large files. It tries to load the whole file into ram.

Answer (score 0):

No sure in Windows, but in Linux you can use combinations of grep, awk and sed. Try finding them in SO. You can refer to the query below.
[Basic grep/sed/awk script to find duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875597/basic-grep-sed-awk-script-to-find-duplicates).

As for split, you can try and use [How to split one text file into multiple *.txt files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031144/how-to-split-one-text-file-into-multiple-txt-files)

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use [010 editor](https://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/). I have edited file of 40GB. It works like a charm.